# About the maximum recursion error in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I am building an application using FastAPI+Sqlalchemy+Mysql, and when I do a stress test,I get an Asgi exception error:

```py
[ERROR] Exception in ASGI application, 
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.
```

I can definitely have :

1. I did not call any recursive function
2. I have tried both alchemy and mysql_connector to query the database
   but the error still exists.

The code is here:

#### My main.py as follows

```py
def create_app()->FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI(debug = False)

    register_cors(app)

    app.include_router(admin_router)

    register_exception(app)
   
    register_token_validate(app)

    return app


***def register_cors(app:FastAPI):
    @app.middleware("http")
    async def cors(request:Request, call_next):
        app.add_middleware(
            CORSMiddleware,
            allow_origins=["*"],
            allow_credentials=True,
            allow_methods=["*"],
            allow_headers=["*"],      
        )
        response = await call_next(request)
        response.headers["access-control-allow-credentials"] = "true"
        response.headers["access-control-allow-origin"] = "*"
        response.headers["access-control-allow-methods"] = "*"
        return response***

def register_exception(app:FastAPI):

    @app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
    async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
        errType = (exc.errors())[0]["type"]
        detail = (exc.errors())[0]
        type = errType.split(".")
        if type[0] == "value_error":
            return JSONResponse(
                status_code=422,
                content={"code": 422,"msg": "value error", "errinfo_type":detail}
            )
        elif type[0] == "type_error":
            return JSONResponse(
                status_code=422,
                content={"code": 422,"msg": "type error", "errinfo_type":detail}
            )
        else:          
            return JSONResponse(
                status_code=422,
                content={"code": 422,"msg": "server error", "errinfo_type":detail}
            )


    @app.exception_handler(Exception)
    async def all_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: Exception):
        return JSONResponse(
            status_code=500,
            content={"code": 500,"msg": "server error", "errinfo_type":None}
        )

def register_token_validate(app: FastAPI):
    @app.middleware("http")
    async def token_validate(request: Request, call_next):
        excludeUrlL = [
            "/v1/login",
            "/docs",
            "/redoc"
        ]

        if (request.url.path not in excludeUrlL) and (request.method != "OPTIONS"): 
            res = security.validate_token(request.headers.get("token"), request.headers.get("request_time"))   
            if res['status'] == "success": 
                response = await call_next(request)
                response.headers["access-control-allow-credentials"] = "true"
                response.headers["access-control-allow-origin"] = "*"
                response.headers["access-control-allow-methods"] = "*"
                return response
            elif res['status'] == "failed": 
                return JSONResponse(
                    status_code=401,
                    content={"code": 401,"msg": "token expired"}
                ) 
            elif res['status'] == "updated": 
                response = await call_next(request)
                response.headers["token"] = res['payload']
                response.headers["access-control-allow-credentials"] = "true"
                response.headers["access-control-allow-origin"] = "*"
                response.headers["access-control-expose-headers"] = "token"
                response.headers["access-control-allow-methods"] = "*"
                return response
        else:
            response = await call_next(request)
            response.headers["access-control-allow-credentials"] = "true"
            response.headers["access-control-allow-origin"] = "*"
            response.headers["access-control-allow-methods"] = "*"
            return response

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app="main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True, debug=False)
```

security.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo
from db.DbSession import session
from sqlalchemy import text

from config import config
from core.logger import logger
from core import util
import pytz


def validate_token(token, request_time):
    if not token:
        return {"status":"failed", "payload":None, "msg": "token is required"}

    if not request_time:
        return {"status":"failed", "payload":None, "msg": "request_time is required"}

    sql = "select id, mobile, token, expired_time,  last_request_time from my_user_table where token = :token limit 1"
    rp = session.execute(text(sql), {"token":token})
    res = [dict(r.items()) for r in rp]

    if not res:
        return {"status":"failed", "payload":None, "msg": "token error"}

    nowStamp =  datetime.now().timestamp()
    expired_timeStamp = res[0]['expired_time'].timestamp()

    if nowStamp > expired_timeStamp:
        return {"status":"failed", "payload":None, "msg": "token is expired"}

    if (int(request_time) - int(res[0]['last_request_time'])) > 600:
        return {"status":"updated", "payload":token, "msg": "token is updated"}
    else:
        return {"status":"success", "payload":None, "msg": "token is valid"}
```

session.py

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

engine = create_engine(config.DbUrl, echo = False, poolclass=NullPool)
session = Session(engine)
```

api.py

```py
@router.get("/v1/getCompany", summary="get company information")
async def getCompany(id:int):
    sql = "select * from my_company_table c where c.id = :id"    
    rp = session.execute(text(sql), {"id":id})
    res = [dict(r.items()) for r in rp]   
    session.commit() 
    return util.resp_200(200, 'get company information success', res)
```

When I call this interface `/v1/getCompany` continuously, I get the above error

```
[ERROR] Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 388, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 179, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 86, in __call__
    await self.simple_response(scope, receive, send, request_headers=headers)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 142, in simple_response
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 86, in __call__
    await self.simple_response(scope, receive, send, request_headers=headers)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 142, in simple_response
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 86, in __call__
    await self.simple_response(scope, receive, send, request_headers=headers)

   ..........


  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 86, in __call__
    await self.simple_response(scope, receive, send, request_headers=headers)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 142, in simple_response
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 74, in __call__
    headers = Headers(scope=scope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/typing.py", line 873, in __new__
    obj = super().__new__(cls)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I have looked up all the relevant questions, but unfortunately have not found the answers,
Now I can only suspect that it is a problem with FastAPI or Starlette, who can give me a solution to the problem, thanks a lot.

After testing, I can solve this problem in this way:`sys.setrecursionlimit(9000000)`, but I think that this should not be the best solution for this kind of problem

Comment: Try remove all the code you can until the error goes away, might help point to what's causing it

Comment: Okay, I'll try it out,I'll provide feedback later,Thank you!!!

Comment: I did a streamlining process to remove all kinds of validation and error handling, but after testing, the error still exists and the version number of the main dependency library is:

fastapi:1.61.2
sqlalchemy:1.3.20
fastapi_sqlalchemy:0.2.1

Comment: I turned off cross-domain processing again, and surprisingly it worked, 10,000 requests, only 1 exception, and I didn't turn on the maximum recursion depth setting, so I think that's the biggest sticking point!

Comment: def register_cors(app:FastAPI):
    @app.middleware("http")
    async def cors(request:Request, call_next):
        app.add_middleware(
            CORSMiddleware,
            allow_origins=["*"],
            allow_credentials=True,
            allow_methods=["*"],
            allow_headers=["*"],      
        )
        response = await call_next(request)
        response.headers["access-control-allow-credentials"] = "true"
        response.headers["access-control-allow-origin"] = "*"
        response.headers["access-control-allow-methods"] = "*"
        return response

Comment: Now I want to know, if the cross-domain settings, what is the problem with writing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer, it is because of the addition of cross-domain caused by the use of middleware way to add cross-domain will cause the maximum number of recursive error, add a separate request header can be.

this is the bad way:

```py
def register_cors(app:FastAPI):
    @app.middleware("http")
    async def cors(request:Request, call_next):
        app.add_middleware(
            CORSMiddleware,
            allow_origins=["*"],
            allow_credentials=True,
            allow_methods=["*"],
            allow_headers=["*"],      
        )

        response = await call_next(request)
        response.headers["access-control-allow-credentials"] = "true"
        response.headers["access-control-allow-origin"] = "*"
        response.headers["access-control-allow-methods"] = "*"
        return response
```

this is the better way:

```py
def register_cors(app:FastAPI):
    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=["*"],
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],      
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`async def cors(request:Request, call_next):`

Bad Way
`request:Request` is Causing the error

after removing it, it works well for me
but this is not the best fix

Good Way
`async def cors( call_next):`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please explain why does `request: Request` cause the error.